# Snowflake: Import data from csv file into temporary table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a way to import data from a csv file into a temporary table on Snowflake? Preferably using the web interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to load a csv file into a temp table from UI. It would be interesting to know the use case for the questions?

Given that Temporary tables only exist within the session in which they were created and persist only for the remainder of the session.

As such, **they are not visible to other users or sessions. Once the session ends, data stored in the table is purged completely from the system and, therefore, is not recoverable, either by the user who created the table or Snowflake.**